# Can OS X Combine Physical Disks

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have OSX Server 10.5.8 installed on a drive and I would like to combine 2 USB drives together to act as one drive.

Is that possible?

Comment: You should check this out: http://lifehacker.com/5986883/how-to-combine-multiple-hard-drives-into-one-volume-for-cheap-high+capacity-storage

Answer (score 2):

Yes - OS X offers software RAID functionality on both the Server version and consumer OS. Open Disk Utility and read through the help on RAID.

> Create a single, large disk from several smaller disks by creating a concatenated disk set, which is also called “Just a Bunch of Disks” (JBOD) or “spanning.” The concatenated disk set acts as one large disk with the combined capacity of all the smaller disks.

You will need to erase/repartition both drives and then can choose from a simple concatenation of the drives or set up striping which has advantages and disadvantages compared to just combining the two drives.